# send data from nodejs to html page

Tags: jquery, node.js, electron

I have a data in json structure in nodejs and I am sending it like shown below

```
mainWindow.loadFile('./app/Logpage.html',response.data)
```

Below is the data contained in response.data

```
[
{'project_name': 'sales',
 'model': {'model_name': '"customer"', 'Status': 'done'}, 
'info': [
{'name': 'dummy_1', 'status': 'done'},
 {'name': 'dummy_2', 'status': 'done'}, 
{'name': 'dummy_3', 'status': 'done'}
]
}
]
```

Is this the correct way of sending?
If yes How can I retreive it in Logpage.html page

Comment: Is the way I am sending data from nodejs to html page correct? Please help me with this

Answer (score 0):

Hello if you are using express.

you can try this, for example.

```
router.get('/coracle-beach', function(req, res, next) {
  var data = {studentList: ["Johnson", "Mary", "Peter", "Chin-su"]};
  res.render('coracle-beach', {students: data});
})
```

Or you can check below link also.

https://steemit.com/utopian-io/@prodicode/how-to-use-ejs-displaying-data-from-nodejs-in-html

Comment: Is ```/coracle-beach``` a html page.If so how can I retreive in that page the data

Comment: @kavya it is page.

Answer (score 0):

To send data, likely from a file (I'm assuming?), you can use this template:

**main.js**

```js
const {
  app,
  BrowserWindow,
  ipcMain
} = require("electron");
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");

// Keep a global reference of the window object, if you don't, the window will
// be closed automatically when the JavaScript object is garbage collected.
let win;

async function createWindow() {

  // Create the browser window.
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: false, // is default value after Electron v5
      contextIsolation: true, // protect against prototype pollution
      enableRemoteModule: false, // turn off remote
      preload: path.join(__dirname, "preload.js") // use a preload script
    }
  });

  // Load app
  win.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, "dist/index.html"));

  // rest of code..
}

app.on("ready", createWindow);

ipcMain.on("toMain", (event, args) => {
  fs.readFile("path/to/file", (error, data) => {
    // Do something with file contents

    // Send result back to renderer process
    win.webContents.send("fromMain", responseObj);
  });
});
```

**preload.js**

```js
const {
    contextBridge,
    ipcRenderer
} = require("electron");

// Expose protected methods that allow the renderer process to use
// the ipcRenderer without exposing the entire object
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
    "api", {
        send: (channel, data) => {
            // whitelist channels
            let validChannels = ["toMain"];
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                ipcRenderer.send(channel, data);
            }
        },
        receive: (channel, func) => {
            let validChannels = ["fromMain"];
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                // Deliberately strip event as it includes `sender` 
                ipcRenderer.on(channel, (event, ...args) => func(...args));
            }
        }
    }
);
```

**index.html**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        // Called when message received from main process
        window.api.receive("fromMain", (data) => {
            console.log(`Received ${data} from main process`);
        });

        // Send a message to the main process
        window.api.send("toMain", "some data");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[Source](https://github.com/reZach/secure-electron-template/blob/master/docs/newtoelectron.md) - I recommend reading this guide.